# Accented characters in JTextField

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

I'm making an application where I use `JTextField` to connect to something (in this case, a database), but when I try to do so with the good login/password, it doesn't work, because some special characters become wrong characters.

example: ç become a Greek letter, é become ù, etc . . .

I think it's a charset problem, but I couldn't find how to fix it.

My code looks like this:

```
JTextField login = new JTextField();
JTextField passw = new JTextField();

JButton connect = new JButton("Connect");
connect.addActionListener( new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            connect(login.getText(), passw.getText());
        }
    });
```

Where `connect()` is my method to connect to the database. 
When I print special characters from the `JTextField.getText()` function, it's all messed up.

I'm running on a Windows 7 PC

Comment: some sample code will help :)

Comment: could be some kind of unsigned char -> char problem.
I don't know how you format your strings.

Comment: _because some specials characters become wrong characters_. How are you showing the characters?. Maybe the error is not in the input of the characters,maybe is in the way you are displaying them

Comment: Are you sure it's the textfield and not the string that you're putting *into* the textfield?  A `JTextField` should support any Unicode character; the problem is likely to be a character-encoding issue in the way you retrieve the string from the database.

Comment: The string I put into the JTextField is just something I type on my keyboard (French Keyboard)

Comment: @Wyzard I don't fill the Text fields with content from a db, I connect to the db with id I get from the text fields

Comment: What happen next? Where do you save the text you get? How do you sout this?

Comment: Oops, my mistake.  But the point is that it may be an encoding problem on your database connection.  Use a debugger to check the string that you from the text field before sending it to the database — and to rule out possible encoding issues related to your *terminal*, maybe write a loop to print each character of the string as an integer, so you can see the actual Unicode codepoint numbers.

Comment: @Watsche Then, I use the JDBC connector to connect to a MySQL db through the java.sql.DriverManager . I don't modify the strings or do anything fancy with them, just use them as arguments for my function that connect to the db.

Comment: ! I launched my application on another pc (windows 8) and the text came out normally, can this be a problem with the computer I'm using ? I'll try to search that way