# How to correct Greek accented characters in a TextField

Tags: java, javafx

The problem I am facing is when I have an input (TextField, TextArea, etc.) and I am trying to insert some Greek words which contain accented characters. Words like " Γάτα " (cat) works fine. Unfortunately, I am unable to **type** words like " Ταϊτή " (Tahiti). If I try to copy and paste it or hard code it, it is working fine, but when I try to write the word using the combination of

Shift + ';' + ι

which should produce the 'ϊ', instead I am getting '¨ι'

Here is an example :

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Example extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

        VBox mainBox = new VBox(10);
        mainBox.setPadding(new Insets(20));
        mainBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        // Ταϊτή = Tahiti
        TextField field1 = new TextField("Ταϊτή");
        TextField field2 = new TextField();

        mainBox.getChildren().add(field1);
        mainBox.getChildren().add(field2);

        field1.setStyle("-fx-font-size:24px");
        field2.setStyle("-fx-font-size:24px");

        stage.setScene(new Scene(mainBox));
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

And the image below show what I have as a result when i type the word myself

[image]

Installed JRE : jre1.8.0_221

Installed JDK : jdk1.8.0_221

To exclude the IDE (Eclipse) as a cause of the problem, I tested this behavior on SceneBuilder with just an AnchorPane and a TextField and I had the same issue there as well. But for the sake of argument, I have the editor and all the settings in the Eclipse to use the encoding UTF-8.

**So I would like to ask: Is this a bug of the current JRE/JDK and if so, is there a well-known solution I could use or I should just use a Listener to catch the input and correct it myself?**

**Edit :** As Sedrick point it out I could use the combination of alt + 0 2 3 9 but this is going to produce a different kind of letter which is similar to the Greek one but not the same. Look the image below. Unfortunately this is not the behavior than my client wants to, because the correct way to type it ( in Greek keyboards ) is with the : Shift + ';' + ι  , where the 'ι' is the English letter 'i'.

[image]

**Edit 2:** Also I could hack my way around it by using the code below but if i decided to do so, I must do it for all of my TextFields which is something i would like to avoid. Otherwise I should create a "dummy" CustomTextField class which will extends the TextField and implement the hack there, then I could replace all the TextField references on my project with the CustomTextField.

```
field2.setTextFormatter(new TextFormatter<>(c -> {
    String text = c.getControlNewText();

    if (text.contains("¨ι") || text.contains("¨Ι")) { 

        // In order to "catch" a word with multiple wrong characters
        // for example if someone tries to copy/paste, I will use
        // the replaceAll() method
        text = text.replaceAll("¨ι", "ϊ");
        text = text.replaceAll("¨Ι", "Ϊ"); 

        // update the field 
        field2.setText(text);

        // correct the caret and anchor positions
        c.setCaretPosition(c.getCaretPosition() - 1);
        c.setAnchor(c.getCaretPosition());

        c.setText(""); // consume change because we already update it
    }
    return c;
}));
```

Comment: Have you tried `al` + `0` `2` `0` `7`  on the keypad?

Comment: Well in your case `alt` + `0` `2` `3` `9`.

Comment: @Sedrick Have a look on the edit on the post, I am sure there is an alternative combination of keys to type it but unfortunately it is not the common way to type it using a Greek keyboards. I believe this is a bug.

Comment: Also, your hack is a good one, but TextFormatter is suggested in cases like this.

Comment: @fuggerjaki61 In my main project i load all the views with FXML which has encoding UTF-8 and i already test it with UTF-16. Also I tried use multiple font families. It is unlikely to be a font problem because otherwise I wouldn't be possible to "hard code' the word in the first place like i did in the example above.

Comment: FWIW someone ran into the same issue 4 years ago at https://www.reddit.com/r/javahelp/comments/2y69co/problem_javafx_textfield_and_trying_to_input/ but I don't see a solution in there. Could this be a bug with `TextField`?

Comment: Also! Here is a similar issue (but for `JTextField`) where the user reported that behavior varied between operating systems. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24017029/accented-characters-in-jtextfield#comment37019439_24017029

Comment: TextField textField = new TextField();
textField.textProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
    String text = newValue;
    if (text.contains("¨ι") || text.contains("¨Ι")) { 

        // In order to "catch" a word with multiple wrong characters
        // for example if someone tries to copy/paste, I will use
        // the replaceAll() method
        text = text.replaceAll("¨ι", "ϊ");
        text = text.replaceAll("¨Ι", "Ϊ"); 

        // update the field 
        field2.setText(text);
});
Why not a simple Listner?

Comment: @Meziane That was my first solution too, but the TextFormatter is the suggested way to handle cases like this'. Probably there is a bug with TextField and I can only deal with it using the 'hack' solution.

Comment: can you extend the TextField and create a re-usable component out of it? Provide your hack as a method for utility in that component and use that component across your project, not sure but suggesting an approach.

Comment: @BilboBaggins More or less your suggestion is exactly what i am describing on "Edit 2" and that is what I am using right now. But still I would love to know if there is a way to avoid using a 'hack' to solve this.

Comment: I will try out your code once I reach home. I will update you here.

Comment: @JKostikiadis check if this article helps https://www.digitalcitizen.life/changing-display-language-used-non-unicode-programs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce the behaviour. If you add an `EventHandler` to your stage you can clearly see the problem.

```
stage.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_TYPED, ev -> {
    System.out.println("Key typed: " + ev.getCharacter());
});
```

Output:

```
Key typed: ¨
Key typed: Ι
Key typed: ¨
Key typed: ι
```

There is a [resolved ticket](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8116603) describing this problem. If its a [Glass Windowing Toolkit](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/architecture/jfxpub-architecture.htm) issue we cannot do much about it, but file a bug report.

I don't know if you can catch the typed keys before these `KeyEvents` are sent but you can filter them at stage level.

```
stage.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_TYPED, new KeyTypedListener());
```

This is not nice but a more "global" way to change behaviour.

```
public class KeyTypedListener implements EventHandler<KeyEvent> {

    private boolean disabled = false;
    private Map<String, String> charCombinations = new HashMap<>();
    private KeyEvent pendingEvent;

    public KeyTypedListener() {
        charCombinations.put("¨ι", "ϊ");
        charCombinations.put("¨Ι", "Ϊ");
    }

    @Override
    public void handle(final KeyEvent event) {

        if (disabled || event.getCharacter() == null
                || event.getCharacter().length() != 1) {
            return;
        }

        final String typed = event.getCharacter();

        if (pendingEvent == null && isCombiCharacter(typed)) {
            pendingEvent = event.copyFor(event.getSource(), event.getTarget());
            event.consume();

        } else if (pendingEvent != null) {
            String combination =
                    charCombinations.get(pendingEvent.getCharacter() + typed);

            if (combination == null) {
                disabled = true;
                fireEvent(pendingEvent);
                disabled = false;
                pendingEvent = null;
            } else {
                event.consume();
                pendingEvent = null;

                Platform.runLater(() -> {
                    fireEventWithCharacter(event, combination);
                });
            }
        }
    }

    private boolean isCombiCharacter(final String character) {
        return "¨".equals(character);
    }

    private void fireEvent(final KeyEvent event) {
        Event.fireEvent(event.getTarget(), event);
    }

    private void fireEventWithCharacter(final KeyEvent event,
            final String character) {
        fireEvent(new KeyEvent(event.getSource(), event.getTarget(),
                event.getEventType(), character, "", KeyCode.UNDEFINED,
                event.isShiftDown(), event.isControlDown(), event.isAltDown(),
                event.isMetaDown()));
    }
}
```

Of course you could also create a new `EventDispatcher`.

Comment: Well more or less the conclusion is that there is bug probably in the mapping of the keys after the key release  event, also your solution is very interesting. It could be a waste to let this bounty to be lost so its yours ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a problem with greek keyboard. I tried use another text fields (Opera search bar, Google search bar etc.) and I couldn't write this character. You can only write this with Alt+0239 combination. You can try create combinations with "field2.setOnKeyPressed()".